# Reset Microsoft Word Settings

Tags: windows, microsoft-word

How do I reset Word to factory settings (options dialogs, auto-correct, indentation, etc) without editing the registry as this [site](http://word.tips.net/Pages/T001330_Factory_Default_Settings_for_Word.html) suggests?  I can edit to registry, but I'd rather not.

I cannot find anything so far in Word to do this.  I am using Office 2007 on Windows XP Pro 64.

Thanks!

Comment: Is reinstalling an option?

Answer (score 0):

That is how Microsoft says to do it also. But if you scroll down to "Repair Word (Office)" there are other methods. support.microsoft.com/kb/822005

> Repair Word (Office) Word can detect and repair problems associated with Setup. This feature uses the Windows Installer to correct
>   problems with missing files and to repair registry settings.
>
> You can use the following three methods to repair or to reset Word
>   files and values:•Method 1: Use the "Detect and Repair" feature
>   •Method 2: Repair Word in Maintenance Mode Setup •Method 3: Reinstall
>   Word (Office)
>
> Method 1: Use the "Detect and Repair" or "Microsoft Office
>   Diagnostics" feature Note This method is the least aggressive mode of
>   repair. If this method does not resolve the problem, you may still
>   have to use one of the other methods.
>
> To run the Detect and Repair feature in Word 2003 and in earlier
>   versions of Word, click Detect and Repair on the Help menu in Word.
>   The Detect and Repair feature fixes and repairs Word. All files,
>   registry entries, and optional shortcuts for all Office programs are
>   verified and repaired. If you run Detect and Repair from Word, all
>   other Office programs are also checked. This feature performs only a
>   checksum.
>
> The Detect and Repair feature can also restore the Word program
>   shortcuts on the Start menu. To restore the Word program shortcuts,
>   click Help, click Detect and Repair, and then click to select the
>   Restore my shortcuts while repairing check box.
>
> If Detect and Repair does not correct the problem, you may have to
>   reinstall Word. The Reinstall feature in the Maintenance Mode dialog
>   box performs the same action as Detect and Repair, except that
>   Reinstall copies a file when the files are of equal versions. Detect
>   and Repair does not copy over the file when the installation file has
>   the correct version and checksum.
>
> Note The Detect and Repair feature does not repair damaged documents
>   or damaged data keys in the registry or in the Normal template.
>
> If a file that Word uses at Startup is missing, the Windows Installer
>   automatically installs that file before it starts the program.
>
> In Word 2007, run the Microsoft Office Diagnostics feature. To do
>   this, click the Microsoft Office Button, click Word Options, click
>   Resources, and then click Diagnose.
>
> In Word 2010, repair Word or the installed Office suite in Control
>   Panel.
>
> Method 2: Repair Word in Maintenance Mode setup Note This method is a
>   moderate mode of repair. If this method does not resolve the problem,
>   you may still have to reinstall Word.
>
> The Maintenance Mode Setup process is similar to the process found in
>   earlier versions of Word. The Maintenance Mode Setup process allows
>   you to repair, add or remove features, and remove the program.
>   "Repair" is a feature in Maintenance Mode that finds and then fixes
>   errors in an installation.
>
> To perform a Maintenance Mode repair, follow these steps:1.Quit all
>   Office programs.
>   2.Use one of the following procedures:◦In Windows 7 or Windows Vista, click Start, and then type add remove. ◦In Windows XP or Windows
>   Server 2003, click Start, and then click Control Panel.
>
> ◦In Windows 2000, click Start, point to Settings, and then click
>   Control Panel.
>
> 3.Open Add or Remove Programs.
>   4.Click Change or Remove Programs, click Microsoft Office (Microsoft Office Word), or the version of Office or Word that you have in the
>   Currently installed programs list, and then click Change.
>   5.Click Repair or Repair Word (Repair Office), and then click Continue or Next.
>   6.In Word 2003 and in earlier versions of Word, click Detect and Repair errors in my Word installation or click Detect and Repair
>   errors in my Office installation. Then, click to select the Restore my
>   Start Menu Shortcuts check box, and then click Install.
>
> Method 3: Reinstall Word (Office) Note This method is the most
>   aggressive mode of repair. This mode resets Word to its default
>   settings, except for settings that are stored in your global template
>   (Normal.dot or Normal.dotm). To do this in Word 2003 and in earlier
>   versions of Word, follow these steps:1.Quit all Office programs.
>   2.Use one of the following procedures:◦In Windows 7 or Windows Vista, click Start, and then type add remove. ◦In Windows XP or Windows
>   Server 2003, click Start, and then click Control Panel. ◦In Windows
>   2000, click Start, point to Settings, and then click Control Panel.
>
> 3.Open Add or Remove Programs.
>   4.Click Change or Remove Programs, click Microsoft Office 2003 (Microsoft Office Word 2003), or the version of Office or Word that
>   you have in the Currently installed programs list, and then click
>   Change.
>   5.Click Repair Word (Repair Office), and then click Next.
>   6.Click Reinstall Word (Reinstall Office), and then click Install.